# How to modify the values of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

the title says it all. 
I've made some research and apparently I can't directly modify the values of an array, is there a way to create a copy of this array (in shape) but with different values?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the code you have done so far

Comment: Python's array is mutable.

Comment: Are you using a tuple (square or circular parentheses)?

Comment: tuple (`(1, 2)`), list (`[1, 2]`), or array (`array.array(1, 2)`). What are you using?

Answer (score 3):

In Python there are arrays, lists and tuples. Arrays and lists are modifiable but tuples aren't. You initialize a list as follows:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l[0] = 2
print l # 2 2 3
```

You initialize an array as follows:

```
a = array('i', [1, 2, 3])
a[0] = 2
print l # array('i', [2, 2, 3])
```

Tuples are initialized as follows:

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
t[0] = 2 # Error tuples are immutable
```

Comment: exists also arrays, [arrays module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array) ..... wait for OP shows the code

Comment: Oh, sorry I figured he meant lists.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Python are mutable.

```
>>> from array import array
>>> a = array('i',[1,2,3,4])
>>> a
array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[0] = 2
>>> a
array('i', [2, 2, 3, 4])
```

Maybe you are thinking of `tuple`? Tuples aren't mutable.

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a[0] = 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

In which case you should probably just use a list? But you can just reassign the tuple to something else:

```
>>> a = (1, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking of is a list, and you are able to modify the entries. An Example:

```
list=[1,2,3]
print list #prints out [1,2,3]
list[0]=5 #changes the first entry in the list to equal 5
print list #prints out [5,2,3]
```